# '""' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 8 I am trying to create a new project with following commands:

1. composer global require laravel/installer
2. laravel new test_project

and receive this:
'""' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLsUa.png)

Comment: your  Windows Environment Variables are messed up..